# Decode number coded with some strange algorithm

Tags: algorithm, encoding

There is such an encoding algorithm: we're given some number `x`, let's say `7923`. We add zeros to the end and the beginning of it - `079230`. Now we sum digits, beginning from the right side - the first digit with the second, the second with the third etc. If the sum is bigger than `9`, we subtract `10` from it and move `1` to the next operation.

So for the example of `079230`: `0+3 = 3`, `3+2=5`, `2+9=11`, `9+7+1=17`, `7+0+1=8`. Our encoded number are the results of the operations, so we end with a number: `87153`.

Now, we are given the encoded number, but with one digit missing - for example  `871X3`. Now we need to decode it - get `7923` from it.

So shortly speaking - `871X3` is the input, the output should be `7923`. Only one digit could be missing.

That is kind of weird problem for me. I guess we need to deduce somehow the original number, maybe with some backtracking? The first digit of original number could be the first digit of encoded number or that digit minus 1. But I can't see any path leading from here to the solution.

Comment: Have you tried anything? At least bruteforce?

Comment: On your example, the result shouldn't be ```8711153``` instead of ```87153```?

Comment: @CosminIoniță No; I confirm 87153.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your algorithm: this is merely performing long multiplication.  The "encoded" number is the original times 11.

Since the multiplier is greater than 9, there can be only one possibility for the missing digit.  Find it with modular arithmetic.  Put in 0 as the missing digit and check:

```
87103 mod 11 ==> 5
```

Now, the "parity" of the number changes with the position.  Counting from the right, even-numbered positions will return the missing digit itself (factors of 0, 99, 9999, 999999, etc. will drop out).  Odd-numbered positions will give the additive inverse: subtract that digit from 11 to get the missing one.  For the given example, try this for each of the digits:

```
87150 mod 11 ==> 8  missing digit is 3 (11-8)
87103 mod 11 ==> 5  missing digit is 5
87053 mod 11 ==> 10 missing digit is 1 (11-10)
80153 mod 11 ==> 7  missing digit is 7
 7153 mod 11 ==> 3  missing digit is 8 (11-3)
```

Answer (score 0):

say the digits of the original number are, from left to right, d,c,b,a.

```
0 + a mod 10 = 3, so a = 3
3 + b mod 10 = 5, so b = 2
2 + c mod 10 = 1, so c = 9
9 + 1 + d mod 10 = 7, so d = 7
7 + 1 mod 10 = 8, as expected.
```

Comment: Generically if you start in the 1s position and go up, you always know what one of the two numbers is and you know what it adds to mod 10 and you know that both numbers are single digits 0-9 which is all the information you need to solve the  equation.